# Repeated Web App Slot Updates in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions App that seems to be repeatedly be cycling through 'Create or Update Web App Slot' and other admin tasks, even when there isn't a recent commit or manual change to the functions code.  Does anyone know how to prevent this?  Thanks

[image]

There is nothing listed in Diagnose > Swap Effects on Availability

[image]

There was one restart due to deployment but that was >40 minutes ago and these slot events are since then

[image]

Comment: Can you share your Function App settings? Also how did you deploy your function app?

Comment: Also, Inorder to avoid slot update, You can make your slot sticky which will not allow your web app slot to swap or update-https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots.md#swap-operations

Comment: You can disable your function from running to avoid the function getting triggered or updated refer here- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/disable-function.md#how-to-disable-functions-in-azure-functions

Comment: Thanks for your help.  We are deploying from bitbucket using 'Deployment Centre'.  But there are no deploys around the times of the logs in the screenshot.  Also we are not doing slot swaps.  The function is in a slot called 'dev' but we're not changing any settings, configuration, or anything outside of the functions.  Is it possible for something in code to trigger this?

Comment: Yes, Even if your Function gets triggered something in your code might be updating the slot as the function is deployed in specific slot

Comment: What sort of thing could trigger updating the slot?

Comment: What you can do is visit > Azure Function App > Diagnose and Solve problems > Check these 2 settings-https://i.imgur.com/Rh88OAu.png

Comment: For example if there's any setting that retreives secrets in your Function app can update the slot

Comment: Diagnose and Solve problems would give you more details, Check there once

Comment: Updated the question with screenshots for those.  Nothing in Swap Effects on Availability.  There are no App Restarts in the timeframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256308/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-marcus).

Comment: It looks like an issue on the backend, I request you to create Azure support request to get this issue resolved so the Engineering team can look into your logs from backend- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: Ok, thank you.  If we create a new Azure Functions app to test might it be possible that works ok?

Comment: Yes, Try creating a new Function App and test it, It should work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried deploying the Function via Bitbucket CI/CD using Azure Functions and the Activity logs did not show any repeated logs:-

***My Bitbucket Function:-***

[image]

***Deployment Center:-***

[image]

***Function Deployed and running successfully:-***

[image]

***Activity Logs:-***

[image]

Try redeploying your Function in a new Function App and check if the Logs repeat.

Also, looks you're facing a transient issue in your account, I would recommend creating an Azure Support request to resolve your error.